# Отобразить контент при наведении jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать по отдельности для каждого элемента? а то при наведении на одну ссылку, появляется контент сразу на двух
https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/mXWoLM

```js
 $('a').hover(function(){
   $('.sub-menu').show();
 },
 function(){
   $('.sub-menu').hide();
 });
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, dolor!
</div>
<a href="">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat amet tempora dolores in.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').show();
   },
   function(){
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').hide();
   });
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque, dolor!
</div>
<a href="">
  menu item
</a>
<div class="sub-menu">
 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat amet tempora dolores in.
</div>
```

Comment: если что-то не понятно, пишите